# How to solve this Valgrind error due to c_str()

Tags: c++, string, char, constants, std

I am tring to write this kind of code:

```
const char* what() const noexcept override
         {
           //just an example of what I have
           int n=3;
             std::string str="Mtm matrix error: Dimension mismatch: "+ n.toString()
             const char* str2 = str.c_str();
             return str2;
         }
```

how ever I keep getting these errors from valgrind because I used `c_str`

```
 Invalid read of size 1
==22582==    at 0x4C30A56: __GI_mempcpy (/builddir/build/BUILD/valgrind-3.13.0/memcheck/../shared/vg_replace_strmem.c:1525)
==22582==    by 0x56CF964: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5
==22582==    by 0x56C4741: fwrite
==22582==    by 0x4ECC8F4: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::__ostream_insert<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*, long)
==22582==    by 0x4ECCBF6: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
==22582==    by 0x402BA9: main
==22582==  Address 0x5a2429a is 26 bytes inside a block of size 111 free'd
==22582==    at 0x4C2B16D: operator delete(void*) (/builddir/build/BUILD/valgrind-3.13.0/coregrind/m_replacemalloc/vg_replace_malloc.c:576)
==22582==    by 0x4EF3B62: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()
==22582==    by 0x403ADE: mtm::Matrix<std::string>::DimensionMismatch::what() const
==22582==    by 0x402B9C: main
==22582==  Block was alloc'd at
==22582==    at 0x4C2A1E3: operator new(unsigned long) (/builddir/build/BUILD/valgrind-3.13.0/coregrind/m_replacemalloc/vg_replace_malloc.c:334)
==22582==    by 0x4EF3A18: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&)
==22582==    by 0x4EF462A: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long)
==22582==    by 0x4EF46D3: std::string::reserve(unsigned long)
==22582==    by 0x4EF493E: std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)
==22582==    by 0x401FF4: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > std::operator+<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&&, char const*)
```

can someone please help me understant how to get rid of this error and still convert `std::string` to `const char*`

Comment: `str` is a local variable. Never return a reference to a local variable or any members of the local variable. They go out of scope at the end of the function  and the reference becomes invalid before you can use it.

Comment: @user4581301 so how should I return it?

Comment: you could make `str` `static` and pray you never have a problem with [re-entrance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reentrancy_(computing)). Probably safe with an exception unless you have multiple threads.

Comment: Wait a sec. You don't need a `string` here at all.This I can give a good answer.

Comment: yes you are right , but I am adding `variable.toString()` to the str in my code

Comment: @user4581301 `static` worked , thank you

Comment: In the duplicate I find an over-arching bit of wisdom--make the string ahead of time--to be pretty good advice.

Comment: Remember that you have to be really <expletive deleted> careful with that `static`. If your code ever allows `what` to be called a second time before you've finished using `str`, it's game over, man.